# Odd duplication in Angular repeater

Tags: angularjs

I am getting some odd behavior when I update the array that a repeater is using from a $watch

This is the HTML

```
<section data-ng-controller="JobsController">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>New Job</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
            <fieldset>

                <div class="form-group" data-ng-controller="DisciplinesController" data-ng-init="find()">
                    <h3>Discipline</h3>
                    <div>

                 <!--clicking these will filter -->
                        <label class="form-control"  data-ng-repeat="discipline in disciplines">
                            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="$parent.dl" checklist-value="discipline"> {{discipline.name}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <!--this is the updated list -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Roles</h3>
                    <div>
                        <label class="form-control"  data-ng-repeat="role in selectedDisciplineRoles">
                            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="roleList" checklist-value="role"> {{role.name}}
                        </label>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>What "Job" are they trying to do?</h3>
                    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                </div>
                <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
                    <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

What I am trying to do is have this model filter on the server and have the client update with the appropriate values

```
'use strict';

// Jobs controller
angular.module('jobs').controller('JobsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Jobs', 'RolesAPI',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Jobs, RolesAPI) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        $scope.$watchCollection("dl", function(){
            var activeDisciplineIds = _.pluck($scope.dl, "_id");
            $scope.selectedDisciplineRoles = [];

            RolesAPI.getByDisciplineIds(activeDisciplineIds)
                .success(function(data){

                    $scope.selectedDisciplineRoles = data;

                    console.log($scope.selectedDisciplineRoles)

                }
           );
        });

    }
]);
```

I don't see any duplicates on the return, however when i click on the checkbox there is a quick duplication of the all the active results, and then the duplicates disappear.

I am open to creating an angualar filter but wasn't able to get it working. Here is the data that I am dealing with.

```
[
{
_id: "547d2ad8b62d3f8bfaf139f8",
user: {
_id: "547648f95413b30000a03e21"
},
base: "547956b0824679a54c9142d2",
__v: 0,
created: "2014-12-02T02:58:32.422Z",
disciplines: [
"5476625147bd3200004bae00"
],
name: "item 1"
},
{
_id: "547d0012b62d3f8bfaf139f7",
user: {
_id: "547648f95413b30000a03e21"
},
base: "547956a6824679a54c9142d1",
__v: 0,
created: "2014-12-01T23:56:02.427Z",
disciplines: [
"5476616347bd3200004badfb",
"547661cb47bd3200004badfd"
],
name: "item 2"
},
{
_id: "547cfea6b62d3f8bfaf139f6",
user: {
_id: "547648f95413b30000a03e21"
},
base: "547956a6824679a54c9142d1",
__v: 0,
created: "2014-12-01T23:49:58.885Z",
disciplines: [
"547661cb47bd3200004badfd",
"5476616347bd3200004badfb"
],
name: "item 3"
}
]
```

The filtering needs to happen based on a match of an array of ids, and those in the disciplines array of the object.

so something like

```
["5476616347bd3200004badfb", "547661cb47bd3200004badfd"]
```

would return item 1 and item 3, not item 2

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting the filter working like this.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('roles').filter('rolesByDiscipline', [
    function() {
        return function(roles, disciplineIds) {
            return roles.filter(function(role) {

                for (var i in role.disciplines) {

                    if (_.pluck(disciplineIds, "_id").indexOf(role.disciplines[i]) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }return false;

            });
        };
    }
]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-controller="RolesController" data-ng-init="find()">
    <h3>Roles</h3>
    <div>
        <label class="form-control"  data-ng-repeat="role in roles |  rolesByDiscipline:$parent.dl">
             <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="roleList" checklist-value="role"> {{role.name}}
        </label>
     </div>
</div>
```